# Dynamic Form Validation Admin Conflict

Tags: forms, validation, dynamic

I am building a database-backed web application with an administrator module and a user module.  The administrator module allows an admin to modify properties of entities stored in the database.  The user module serves dynamically generated forms based on the state of the database.

Consider the following use case:

1. A user requests a web page containing a form where the form options presented represent DB entities that meet a certain criteria
2. The requested page containing the dynamically generated form loads.
3. The admin makes changes in the DB to some entities loaded in the form such that they no longer meet the criteria to be displayed in the form (ie inactivated, deassociated)
4. The user submits the form with at least one entity selected that no longer meets the criteria to be displayed in the form.

Should the server-side validation of the submitted form pass or fail in this scenario?

The user was served a valid form but the posted form content is no longer valid with respect to the current state of the DB due to admin changes while the user was on the page...

If it should pass, should I be validating the data against the state of the database when the page loaded (leveraging the database history or using the session) or is that overkill and instead I could just validate that the posted entity is valid but does not necessarily meet the current form criteria?

Answer (score 0):

its better if you dont change db properties. changing db properties will cause errors in your webapplication. try to make a form for admin in which the value of the forms is taken and displayed from the database. in this way only the values contained in the db will be modified by admin. by using this method your db properties will remain intact. And try not to give admin direct access to db.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion or how it relates to my question.  I'm sorry if I was unclear.  When I said the admin is changing db properties I did not mean the admin is changing the table structures or schema but rather changing values and/or inserting/updating rows.

Comment: My main issue is how should I treat a posted form containing stale data?  The data is stale because an admin modified particular values in the database via an admin interface that were used to display the dynamic form a user had already loaded and begun filling out but had not yet posted.  When the data is posted, should it be treated as valid or invalid?  Any ideas on how such a scenario is typically addressed or avoided?

Answer (score 0):

The treatment should be similar to how a "Lost Update" problem is handled, as this IS a lost update problem. Two people pick up a row to edit at the same time, whose changes are persisted and whose changes are lost? The first guy's changes are persisted and the second guy is notified that the update failed - is the standard approach. In this case, the admin is the first guy to update - though the user might have been the first guy to read. So, the validation fails and the user is notified that the data is stale and presented with current data.

Hope this helps.